# Strange behavior of ProgressDialog's key listener in Android

Tags: android

I wrtie a small program to test ProgressDialog in Android.

```
    DialogInterface.OnKeyListener dialogKey = new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
            switch(arg1) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
                Log.i("Spinner Key", "Key Volume Down");
                            Log.i("Spinner Key", "" + arg0.toString());
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:    
                Log.i("Spinner Key", "Key Volume Up"); 
                            Log.i("Spinner Key", "" + arg0.toString());
                return true;                
            default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    };            


        this.mypDialog = new ProgressDialog(SensorDefenceActivity.this);             
        this.mypDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        this.mypDialog.setTitle("Count");
        this.mypDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        this.mypDialog.setMessage(this.start + "");
        this.mypDialog.setCancelable(false);
        this.mypDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        this.mypDialog.setButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i)
            {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        mypDialog.setOnKeyListener(dialogKey);
        mypDialog.show();   
        mypDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
```

When the dialog shows, I press one of the volume keys. But I get the same key press notification in logcat twice!

```
06-08 17:54:07.130: I/Spinner Key(11636): Key Volume Up
06-08 17:54:07.130: I/Spinner Key(11636): android.app.ProgressDialog@402bdd78
06-08 17:54:07.260: I/Spinner Key(11636): Key Volume Up
06-08 17:54:07.260: I/Spinner Key(11636): android.app.ProgressDialog@402bdd78
06-08 17:54:11.320: I/Spinner Key(11636): Key Volume Down
06-08 17:54:11.320: I/Spinner Key(11636): android.app.ProgressDialog@402bdd78
06-08 17:54:11.530: I/Spinner Key(11636): Key Volume Down
06-08 17:54:11.530: I/Spinner Key(11636): android.app.ProgressDialog@402bdd78
```

I promise that the press time is very short so that it can't trigger the same key press message twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onKey` is executed for Both `KeyEvent.ACTION_UP` and `KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN`. (ie `arg2`)

Execute your code for just one of them. I think `ACTION_DOWN` should be the one.